Spring boot (2.7.14) + Thymeleaf - Template con múltiples formularios falla

estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de gestionar templates con varios formularios.
Tengo una aplicación con un menú superior donde se encuentra el botón de logout, que está dentro de un formulario, este menú es un fragment que se inserta en el resto de los templates de la aplicación.
Si lanzo el logout me da error porque siempre ejecuta el último formulario del template, como el logout se carga primero siempre intenta lanzar el submit de la pantalla donde se encuentre. Esto lo solucioné poniendo un evento general que ejecute el logout cuando se pulse sobre el botón con id #btnLogout.
Pero ahora me encuento con el siguiente escenario, tengo una pantalla en la que deseo poder realizar una búsqueda con la que cargar un listado, luego seleccionar del listado los registros que quiera y realizar una solicitud con esos datos. Para ello me gustaría tener 2 formularios, uno que tenga relacionado un objeto de tipo filtro y otro con el listado, de manera que el primero realice un get para realizar la búsqueda y el segundo haga un post para realizar la acción.
He probado todas las soluciones que encontré en stackoverflow y no me ha funcionado ninguna, es decir, he creado múltiples formularios y no me ha servido, he puesto los botones con params y tampoco me ha servido.
Lo que me gustaría sería tener algo como:
<form th:id="formBuscar" th:action="@{/buscar} th:object="${filtro} method="get">
     <button type="submit">BUSCAR</button>
</form>

<form th:id="formPedir" th:action="@{/pedir}" th:object="${items}" method="post">
     <button type="submit">PEDIR</button>
</form>

He probado eso pero siempre ejecuta el submit del formPedir.
He intentado a cambiar la configuración del SpringSecurity, incluso desactivarlo, por si acaso el problema podría venir por ahí, pero el comportamiento es el mismo.
¿Algo que se me esté escapando?
Muchas gracias.

Hola Senses, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código y los mensajes de error (si es que los recibes) en formato texto, y que nos expliques en que falla, mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!
